# Add data to ListView Items WPF

Tags: wpf

How do I add data to the WPF ListView items like Windows Forms?

Comment: Why don't you bind the items to some collection and add items to that collection. That is more in the spirit of WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Using databinding you can bind the itemssource to something like an observable collection then have your items added to that.

This approach makes it fairly easy to manipulate the data once you get used to databinding as long as you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented your listview will update when you call OnPropertyChanged().